# Как указать несколько условий и значений при удалении?

Tags: postgresql

Нужно чтобы удалились все, а не первый. То есть у меня есть массив из двух значений(id и parent_id, это уникальный индекс состоящий из двух значений)  надо в одном запросе удалить все элементы массива.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE (id=4 AND parent_id = 6) OR (id=5 AND parent_id = 6) OR (id=5 AND parent_id=12)
```

Comment: Мне кажется вы чего то не договариваете. Данный запрос удалит все записи в которых (id=4 И parent=6) так же и все записи по остальным условиям. Т.е. он должен сделать именно то, что вы пишите, он якобы не делает. Либо вы хотите не совсем этого, но плохо описали что требуется. попробуйте привести пример входных данных и указать удаление каких записей из примера вы ожидаете

Comment: Не проверял, мне казалось должен быть специальный синтаксис.

Comment: вот как раз что бы удалить не все, потребуется специальный синтаксис. если условия не указать будут удалены вообще все записи из таблицы, условия сокращают количество удаляемого

Comment: точно, перепутал. Думал он остановится на 1 варианте и прекратит дальше удалять.

Comment: Это должно работать и так, да. Можно, из интереса, переписать в нечто вроде `(id, parent_id) IN ((4, 6), (5, 6), (5, 12))` Но стоит семь раз отмерить.